# C# DateTime variable outside foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

I am using WebClient to retrieve a set of data. After receiving the data, I need to loop trough it. I need to know the what was the maximum value of date within the data, so new data can be retrieved from following date.

Simplified, my code looks like:

```
class MyClass
{
    public DateTime LoopDate()
    {
        DateTime[] TripDates = { DateTime.Parse("2019-01-01"), DateTime.Parse("2019-01-02"), DateTime.Parse("2019-01-03") };

        DateTime maxdate;

        foreach (var date in TripDates)
        {
            maxdate = date;
            Console.WriteLine(date);

        }

        return maxdate; //needs to return the maximum DateTime value from the loop 
    }

}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var MyClass = new MyClass();
        var Nextdate = MyClass.LoopDate();
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

}
```

Comment: What's the issue exactly? Are you looking for DateTime.Compare()?

Comment: Try with linq `Max`, `TripDate.Max()`.

Comment: Only assign `date` to `maxdate` if `date` is greater than `maxdate`.  Use an `if` statement to check this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public DateTime LoopDate()
{
    DateTime[] TripDates = { DateTime.Parse("2019-01-01"), DateTime.Parse("2019-01-02"), DateTime.Parse("2019-01-03") };

    DateTime maxdate = TripDates.Max();

    return maxdate; //needs to return the maximum DateTime value from the loop 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below line will work for you

```
DateTime maxdate = TripDates.Max();
```

Comment: already answered

Comment: @MarcoSalerno, that's the obvious fact (mouseover "answered ... ago" line to see tooltip with exact time), no need to point that out ;) And btw because of grace period (edits within 5 min combined and don't go into history) we can't say for sure what you didn't do that: 1) you posted wrong answer 2) Simonare posted his 3) you seen his answer and quickly corrected your 4) then you add comment 5) all upvotes goes to your answer 6) Simonare cry now